# Regex how to match two similar numbers in separate match groups?

Tags: regex

I got the following string:

> [13:49:38 INFO]: Overall : Mean tick time: **4.126** ms. Mean TPS:
>   **20.000**

the bold numbers should be matched, each into its own capture group.

My current expression is `(\d+.\d{3})` which matches **4.126** how can I match my 20.000 now into  a second capture group? Adding the same capture group again makes it find nothing. So what I basically need is, "search for first number, then ignore everything until you find next digit."

Comment: Why don't you use the `g` ("global") flag, or functional equivalent in your (secret?) programming language?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like so: `(\d+\.\d{3}).+?(\d+\.\d{3})$` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/yP8tO2/1)) which essentially is your regex (plus a minor fix) twice, with the difference that it will also look for the same pattern again at the end of the string.

Another minor note, your regex contains, a potential issue in which you are matching the decimal point with the period character. In regular expression language, the period character means *any character*, thus your expression would also match `4s222`. Adding an extra `\` in front makes the regex engine treat is as an actual character, and not a special one.

Comment: Thanks your comment was helpful. Basically the ```.+?``` did the trick.